# Asp MVC This site cannot provide a secure connection <IP> sent an invalid response. error

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am working on asp.net MVC project in Visual Studio 2022 community version and published it on a server it works fine with the URL **http://localhost:8080/myoroject** locally but when a client device tries to access the project via server IP **http://192.*.*.*:8080/myproject** client gets This site cannot provide a secure connection <192.*.*.*> sent an invalid response. error and all CSS & Js resources respond with **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR**

[image]
I don't know why the initial HTTP request is redirected to HTTPs request
[image]

- I have made sure to change the project URL to HTTP and SSL Enabled to false
- I have made sure web.config doesn't have STS configuration
- I have made sure to query the domain and found no lists cached via chrome://net-internals/#hsts

I am expectation for the client device to access the project via an IP address of the server and get a response but currently, the system is redirecting them to HTTPs instead of the initial HTTP request

Comment: The content in your first image doesn't seem to be from a browser, or at least not from one I know. Is there a chance your client has some antivirus software installed, or their networking requires HTTPS to access websites?

Comment: It is a response from Yandex Browser but in Chrome it is This site can't be reached IP refused to connect ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: The issue is with the URL being redirected to HTTPs for example when I manually change the request URL from HTTPs to HTTP it will load the resource for libraries and will route correctly

Comment: Did your remove `app.UseHttpsRedirection` from your startup code? IIRC it's there by default.

Comment: The project I am using is ASP.NET Web Application(.NET Framework), not MVC Core

Comment: I am using asp.net MVC, not asp.net core

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler or the developer tools in your browser to inspect network traffic. Look for any HTTP to HTTPS redirects and investigate the cause of these redirects.

Comment: Thanks after checking old working publish files with the current published file I found that the layout page doesn't match, and the issue was with the meta tag with content security policy When this directive is present in the CSP, the browser will automatically upgrade HTTP requests to HTTPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue, it was a meta tag from the project layout `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">`
located in  `Views/Shared/_Layout.chtml` that was forcing HTTP to HTTPs redirecting.
[_layout page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqbec.png)